# How to search through XML to find bad nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a large XML file (68Mb), I am using SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio 2008 to extract the XML data into a database. There is an error in the XML file some where that prevents it from executing. Possibly a missing tag or something like that. The file is so large I cant manually sort through it looking for the error.

Below is a sample of the the XML schema used.

How can I use XPath to sort through the XML in VS 2012 using C#?

An example would be great!

```
-<PhoneNumberList>

<PhoneNumber value="1234567890" type="Phone"/>

</PhoneNumberList>


-<YearsOfServiceList>

<YearsOfService experienceInMonths="24" description="SuperAdmin" objectCode="049"/>

</YearsOfServiceList>

</Person>


-<Person dob="1960-01-09T00:00:00" lastName="Smith" middleName="Will" firstName="John"     id="9999-9999-9999">


-<SiteList>


-<Site id="2014" siteLongName="HA" siteCode="1255" systemCode="999">


-<StaffPositionList>

<StaffPosition id="73" staffPosition="Administrator"/>

</StaffPositionList>

</Site>

</SiteList>


-<ProgramList>

 <Program id="1234" siteLongName="ABC" siteCode="0000" systemCode="205"/>

 <Program id="5678" siteLongName="DEF" siteCode="0000" systemCode="357"/>

 </ProgramList>


 -<TypeList>

 <Type Description="Leader" certificateType="D"/>

 <Type Description="Professional" certificateType="P"/>

 </TypeList>


-<EmailList>

<Email value="jsmith@somesite.com" type="Email"/>

</EmailList>


-<PhoneNumberList>

<PhoneNumber value="1234567890" type="Phone"/>

</PhoneNumberList>


-<YearsOfServiceList>

<YearsOfService experienceInMonths="24" description="SuperAdmin" objectCode="049"/>

</YearsOfServiceList>

</Person>


</PersonList>

</GetPersonDetail>
```

Comment: Create an XML file in visual studio, paste in the file. You should get warnings about invalid XML. If the problem is that it doesn't follow a particular XML schema (additional constraints on a valid XML file), then you'll need to research xsd validation. But you haven't mentioned xsd's yet.

Comment: Just to verify the easy stuff, you aren't opening the xml file in IE and then copy/pasting that to where-ever? Those -'s are the signs of copy paste and creates XML that the consumer isn't going to be expecting because of all the -'s where it expects white space.

Comment: I did only to put the code in here. The file is large and VS and notepad++ lock up when i try to open the file in them

Comment: That IE can parse and display it is a clue. Look for &'s too. Some xml parsers are willing to deal with &'s other parsers are strict and make you escape your & to &amp; So if the source data had & and wasn't xml escaped, you'll have text with PB&J and other such strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in code then create an XSD file describing a valid format for the data, embed it as a resource in your app and then use code like this

```
var errors = new List<string>();
var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemaSet.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Properties.Resources.NameOfXSDResource)));
document.Validate(schemaSet, (sender, args) =>
    {
        errors.Add(args.Message);
    }
);
```

This will give you a list of validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to search "by hand" if you use a competent text editor.  NotePad++'s XML plugin, for instance, can determine if your XML as a whole is well-formed or valid, and both instances will provide separate error messages.

If you don't have a schema and the file is well-formed, you can use the CLR's `System.XML` namespace to read in the document and then iterate through its nodes using LINQ-to-XML, which would allow you to very finely control which nodes go where.  With LINQ, you could either create a new XML file with only the valid entries, procedurally correct the invalid entries as you determine where they are, or even just write to your SQL server database directly.

Your troubleshooting process should be something as follows:

1. Is the XML **well-formed**?  I..e, does it comport to the fundamental rules of XML?
2. Is the XML **valid**?  I.e., does it have the elements and attributes you expect?
3. Is your import query accurate?

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I usually have luck checking and fixing the data in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). Install the XmlTools plugin and that has a menu for checking the xml syntax and tags.

Also, those dashes will give you problems, it's best to save out the xml file directly without copying by hand.

Comment: My XML File is so large that it freeze up Notepad++. Also when it does open the XML is in a single line. I could be missing the plugin though.

Comment: I added the plugin and Notepad++ formats the XML so that it is readable now.

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as such. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

A 68MB XML file is no problem for XML editors such as XMLBlueprint 64-bit (http://www.xmlblueprint.com/) or Stylus Studio (http://www.stylusstudio.com/). Just check the well-formedness of your xml file (F7 in XMLBlueprint) and the editor will display the errors.